# Empty String elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I'm using Elastic 6.5 .

I need to include an empty string search with one of the criteria i'm passing.

primaryKey = 1, 2, 3

subKey = "" or subKey = "A"   along with a bunch of other criteria.

I've been unable to get the record that has the empty subKey.

i've tried using the MUST_NOT EXISTS but it doesn't fetch the record in question.

So below should return any records that have primarykey of 1, 2, or 3. and subKey of 'A' or Empty String. Filtered by the Date provided.  I get all the records Except the record where the subKey is blank.

so i've tried this:

```
{
  "size": 200, "from": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [{
                "bool": {
                  "should": [{ "terms": {"primaryKey": [1,2,3] }}]
                }
              },
              {
                "bool": {
                  "should": [ 
                              {"match": {"subKey": "A"}}, 
                              {
                                "bool" : {
                                  "must_not": [{ "exists": { "field": "subKey"} }]
                                }
                              }
                            ]
                }
              }],
      "filter": [{"range": {"startdate": {"lte": "2018-11-01"}}}]
    }
  }
}
```

The subkey field is special.. where it's actually searched by LETTER.  But i don't think that effects anything.. but here is the NEST coding i have for that index.

```
new CreateIndexDescriptor("SpecialIndex").Settings(s => s
                .Analysis(a => a
                        .Analyzers(aa => aa
                            .Custom("subKey_analyzer", ma => ma
                                .Tokenizer("subKey_tokenizer")
                                .Filters("lowercase")
                            )
                        )
                        .Tokenizers(ta => ta
                            .NGram("subKey_tokenizer", t => t
                                .MinGram(1)
                                .MaxGram(1)
                                .TokenChars(new TokenChar[] { TokenChar.Letter, TokenChar.Whitespace })
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
                .Mappings(ms => ms
                    .Map<SpecialIndex>(m => m
                        .Properties(p => p
                            .Text(s => s
                                .Name(x => x.subKey)
                                .Analyzer("subKey_analyzer")
                            )
                        )
                    ));
```

Any ideas on how to resolve this?  Thank you very much!

NOTE: i've seen posts saying this can be done with a filter, using missing. But as you can see from the query, i need the Query to do this, not the filter.

i've also tried the following rather than the MUST_NOT EXISTS

```
{
    "term": { "subKey": { "value": "" }}
}
```

but doesn't work. I'm thinking I need another tokenizer to get this working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I managed to fix this by using Multi-fields.  This is what i did.

Changed the Mappings to this:

```
                  .Mappings(ms => ms
                    .Map<SpecialIndex>(m => m
                        .Properties(p => p
                            .Text(s => s
                                .Name(x => x.subKey)
                                .Fields(ff => ff
                                    .Text(tt => tt
                                        .Name("subKey")
                                        .Analyzer("subKey_analyzer")
                                    )
                                    .Keyword(k => k
                                        .Name("keyword")
                                        .IgnoreAbove(5)
                                    )
                                )
                            )
                        )
                    ));
```

then i changed my query BOOL piece to this:

```
            "bool": {
                "should": [{
                    "match": {
                        "subKey.subKey": {
                            "query": "A"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "term": {
                        "subKey.keyword": {
                            "value": ""
                        }
                    }
                }]
            }
```

what i don't really like about this is that i think Elastic is creating an additional field just to find EMPTY strings of the same field.  That really doesn't seem ideal.

Anyone have another suggestion that would be great!

[UPDATE] The NEST implementation needs to use SUFFIX to access the multi-fields.

```
.Bool(bb => bb
   .Should(bbs => bbs
      .Match(m => m.Field(f => f.subKey.Suffix("subKey")).Query(search.subKey)),
      bbs => bbs
      .Term(t => t.Verbatim().Field(f => f.subKey.Suffix("keyword")).Value(string.Empty)))
```

Comment: Were you writing your original query with NEST? If so, did you look at the query generated? Searching for an empty string in a `term` query will trigger _conditionless_ behaviour, so it may be worth looking at this. See second part of answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37714606/1831

Comment: Ok, there is a problem above... my NEST is not producing the BOOL piece like i mentioned.  Yes, changing the DSL works but not what i had in the NEST.  So i'm trying to figure out how to specify the {"term": { "subKey.keyword": { "value": "" }}   right now it is doing  {"term": {"subKey" : {"value" : ""}}  in NEST.

Comment: Ok, wasn't using Suffix.    @RussCam  But to answer your question regarding conditionless behavior, the NEST does 'now' create a dsl query that searches the empty string.  confirmed the query generated by NEST.  And it does return the empty records as intended. Maybe the Verbatim handles the problem you mention?   Is there a different way to handle this?

Comment: Since no one is posting an alternative to this solution, i'll post this one as the solution.

Comment: `.Verbatim()` overrides the conditionless behaviour on queries, to allow you to perform a `term` query with an empty string